# Updating one df based on data in another df

Tags: r

I've searched the website and there are a few solutions on updating one df from another but they don't give me a solution to use multiple variables as criteria.

I have a database which has spend information in it and What I am trying to do is update a specific list with the summary of the spend.

```
df1:                    
Invoice Supplier  OA    Period  Spend   
1   A     A1    P1  100
2   A     0 P1  500 
3   A     A1    P1  300 
4   A     A1    P2  50  
5   B     0 P3  25  
6   B     0 P3  20  
7   B     0 P3  5   
8   C     C5    P1  30  
9   C     C5    P1  35  
10  C     D10   P1  5



df2                 
Supplier  OA                
A     0
A     A1                
B     0
C     C5
```

Result Expected

```
df2                 
Supplier  OA  Spend-P1  Spend-P2  Spend-P3  Total
A     0   500               500
A     A1  400   50          450
B     0           50        50
C     C5  65                65
```

I've tried using an update sql query

```
sqldf("UPDATE df1, df2 SET df2.[Spend-P1] = sum(Spend) WHERE dfa.[OA] = df2.[OA] and df1.[Supplier] = df2.[Supplier] and df1.[Period] = 'P1'")
```

but I'm getting the error message

> Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : near ",": syntax
>   error

Answer (score 0):

I started by taking the `Invoice` column off.

```
df1[-1]%>%group_by(Supplier,OA,Period)%>%
         mutate(Spend=sum(Spend))%>%right_join(df2)%>%
         subset(!duplicated(.))%>%spread(Period,Spend)%>%
         cbind(Tot=rowSums(.[-(1:2)],T))%>%ungroup()
#Joining, by = c("Supplier", "OA")
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  Supplier    OA    P1    P2    P3   Tot
     <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1        A     0   500    NA    NA   500
2        A    A1   400    50    NA   450
3        B     0    NA    NA    50    50
4        C    C5    65    NA    NA    65
```

Comment: i hope this is what you desired